# Problem creation multiples ggplot with a list of dataframes, stored in a list of plot

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, tidyr

I have this list of dataframes
[image]

i want to generate the same plot for each of dataframe. (the columns of interest share the same name, that are : " COType ; Zscore ; SpatialLag ".
Here's my code plotting a single dataframe (Community) :

```
ggplot(List_df_EU[["COMMUNITY"]], aes(x = Zscore, 
                       y = SpatialLag,
                       fill = COType)) + 
  geom_point(color = "white", shape = 21, size = 2) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.7) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.7) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_values) + 
  labs(title = names(List_df_EU[1]),
       subtitle = "Graph de Moran sur les scores ESG des entreprises EU",
       x = "z-score",
       y = "Spatial lag",
       fill = "Type de voisinage")+
  theme_fivethirtyeight()+
  theme (axis.title = element_text(), text = element_text(family = myFont1))
```

[image]
Here's the code supposed to create a single plot for each dataframe. it doesn't fill the list and doesn't send error message back

```
plotlist <- vector()

plotlist <- for(i in 1:length(List_df_EU)) {                              
 ggplot(List_df_EU[[i]], aes(x = Zscore, 
                                      y = SpatialLag,
                                      fill = COType)) + 
  geom_point(color = "white", shape = 21, size = 2) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.7) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.7) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_values) + 
  labs(title = names(List_df_EU[[i]]),
       subtitle = "Graph de Moran sur les scores ESG des entreprises EU",
       x = "z-score",
       y = "Spatial lag",
       fill = "Type de voisinage")+
  theme_fivethirtyeight()+
  theme (axis.title = element_text(), text = element_text(family = myFont1))
}
```

If you have any tips it would be awesome!(Would be deseperate move generating plots manually)

Comment: `for` returns `NULL` invisibly.  Convert to `lapply` or similar and then, if your plotting code is correct, you should be good to go.  For example, `plotlist <- lapply(List_df_EU, function(df) df %>% ggplot() ... )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the same `ggplot` code over a list of dataframes, I think `lapply` is better than a for loop. Try this:

```
plotlist <- lapply(names(List_df_EU), function(x) {
  ggplot(List_df_EU[[x]], aes(x = Zscore, 
                y = SpatialLag,
                fill = COType)) + 
    geom_point(color = "white", shape = 21, size = 2) + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.7) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.7) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = color_values) + 
    labs(title = x,
         subtitle = "Graph de Moran sur les scores ESG des entreprises EU",
         x = "z-score",
         y = "Spatial lag",
         fill = "Type de voisinage")+
    theme_fivethirtyeight()+
    theme (axis.title = element_text(), text = element_text(family = myFont1))
}
```

Comment: Works fine, except that the `labs(title = names(x),` names each plot according to the name of the first column (OBJECTID) of each dataframe, instead of the name of the dataframe itself (community for example). I've tried to substitute with `names(List_df_EU)` or `names(List_df_EU[[i]])` but doesn't work. Since I'm less used to lapply I didnt managed to find a solution.

Comment: @MathiasLauber Then instead of looping over the list, loop over the names. See if this solved your problem :)

Comment: it works great, now plots are mentionning names of dataframe in their title. but on a down side, plots lost their name in the `plotlist` (referring to dataframe), instead they are simply numbered from 1 to 15. I'm currently trying to reattribute dataframe name to plots in plotlist

Comment: It seems that `names(plotlist) <- names(List_df_EU)` did the trick so thank you for everything

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that you're assigning the new plot to plotlist at every iteration of the loop and the previous iteration is being overwritten.

You'd need to assign the new iteration to a new index of the list.
e.g.

```
for (i in listOfPlotsToMake) 
{
plotlist[[i]] <- listOfPlotsToMake[i]...

}
```

Comment: Your explanation is incorrect.  OP is making no assignment within their `for` loop, so nothing is overwritten.  Instead, they are assigning the return value from the `for` loop to a list.  But the `for` loop returns `NULL`, regardless of what is done inside the loop.

Comment: Great call out.